# Thread-safe replacement of ObservableCollection<T> in C# 4.0, with safe enumeration

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, thread-safety, observablecollection

**I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` in one of my projects and I need to make access thread-safe.** 
In particular, I need to have a thread-safe enumerator. This means, during iterating over the collection (e.g. during a LINQ query), no one should be able to add an item.

I noticed the classes in the .NET 4.0 namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent`. However none of them seems to match. Plus, in the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx), I did not find a paragraph about which accesses actually *are* thread-safe.

**Is there an existing thread-safe collection somewhere, that I can use, or must I implement that myself?**

Comment: *during iterating over the collection (e.g. during a LINQ query), no one should be able to add an item.* What should happen if someone tries to add an item to the collection while you are iterating over it? Should it throw an exception? Block? Succeed but not show up in the iteration?

Comment: @ Mark, thanks for your thought. I would like it to block the update.

Comment: Try the following link which provides a thread-safe solution that works from any thread and can be bound to via multiple UI threads : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multithreaded-ObservableImmutableCollection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bear in mind that if you take out a lock in the `GetEnumerator` method, you could be holding a lock for a very long time, during which time no one will be able to add objects to your collection:

```
foreach (var o in myCollection) {
    // Do something that takes 10 minutes
}
```

You also need to think about what happens if multiple iterations are happening at the same time. That means some sort of MRSW lock (multiple reader single writer), which you might have to implement yourself.

It sounds like what you actually need to do is to iterate over a snapshot of the collection:

```
foreach (var o in myCollection.ToArray()) {
    // ...
}
```

To do this properly, you will need to implement your own `ICollection<T>` that takes out a lock in the `ToArray` and `Add` methods

It might help if you give your requirements or specification more precisely.

Comment: Thanks, thecoop, for that enlightening answer. I now use a simple lock()'ed call while reading from the collection. This is a relatively short call and I can live with the fact that others are blocked. Good to know that there are the options you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection is not thread safe. Implement your own thread safe wrapper over it.